# Xcode 8 End Closure Autocompletion Issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, closures, swift3

Relatively new to IOS & Xcode from an Android background, I've found in a few tutorials pressing return on an ending closure and Xcode formatting it in a special way. In my case however, this does not always work.

What happens before and after Enter is pressed for Me
[image]
[image]

What I've seen and would like it to do. 
[image]

Another Example as mentioned by this video(Start 13.06, End 13.16)
https://youtu.be/v9JtVJUxX7k?t=13m6s

Compared to other IDE's Xcode is very buggy currently so its hard to tell if this is just a bug or if I'm doing something wrong. Is anyone able to guide me on how I can go about acheiving this or why its happening?

Comment: Don't update your question with the solution. Instead, post an actual answer if the other answers don't already provide the best solution. Otherwise accept one of the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

It appears for Xcode 8.1 autocomplete for trailing closures must be taken care of before any other placeholders. Switching to Xcode 8.2 also solved this problem.

For Example within the image, the trailing closure would have to be autocompleted before the request placeholder was edited to acheive the desired effect. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell for sure from your screenshot, but it looks like you aren't hitting the Return key while the completion handler placeholder is actually *selected*.  You have to either tab to it, or click on the placeholder.  In your color scheme I believe the placeholder background color will become more saturated  and the text color inside the placeholder block will become dark instead of light. In this selected placeholder state, pressing the Return key creates the trailing closure syntax you are hoping for.

For what it's worth, I typed the exact same code you have in your example above in Xcode 8.2 beta 2, and when I select the placeholder block and press Return, I get the trailing closure syntax as expected 5 out of 5 times.

Comment: Thanks for testing this as well, It appears as though after some playing around that if you want to autocomplete the trailing closure, it has to be the first thing you do. For example in the image examples I provided, If i entered the value for "request" and then tried to autocomplete the closure, it wouldn't work. Yet vice versa it does exactly what I want. Is this the case for you as well?

Comment: @Rykuno  Hmmm... that's strange. That isn't how it behaves for me.  I can enter other parameters, delete other placeholders, etc. As long as I don't change or delete the completion handler placeholder along the way, I can always tab or reverse tab to it and press Return, or click it and press Return, or just double-click it. All of those methods work 100% for creating a trailing closure.  Are you using the latest beta of Xcode, or an earlier version?

Comment: Currently running version 8.1. I'll go ahead and download the beta to give it a try. A friend running the same version just got back to me and confirmed the autocompletion for trailing closures wasn't working unless you autocomplete them first too. This along with others saying they removed it in Version 8 make me think maybe its just something weird for this version? None the less, I'll get back when I'm done downloading 8.2 to see if its just a 8.1 thing incase others have this same problem.

Comment: @Rykuno  sounds good.  I never used 8.1 but I've verified that the behavior is correct on 8.0 and 8.2 beta 2  :)

Comment: Yep, works for me on 8.2 as you described in your post as well. I guess its just an 8.1 thing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rykuno  Glad it's working again. Xcode is, as you said above, very buggy compared to other IDEs   :\   AppCode is worth giving a try and tends to be a lot better about these sorts of things, and more customizable.